# Aligning flex items to row difficult in my code

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Please i have tried all possible means to align my .shirt-box to row but it has proved abortive. My code is below. thanks for your unusual assistance. I have tried several answers here but they have also proved abortive. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```css
.shirt-box {
 -ms-flex: 0 0 300px;
    flex: 0 0 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url("Blue_Tshirt.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 cursor: pointer;
 /*margin: 0 auto;*/
 /*margin: 0 40px;*/
 /*float: left;*/
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.shirt-box:hover {
 transform: translateY(-3px);
}
.container-flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow:row wrap;
 align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="centerpage">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row container-flex">
   <div class="col shirt-box">
       
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row container-flex">
   <div class="col shirt-box">
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Can you expand upon what you mean by `align my .shirt-box to row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html like as shown below. Remove the extra container and row divs

```css
.shirt-box {
 -ms-flex: 0 0 300px;
    flex: 0 0 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url("Blue_Tshirt.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 cursor: pointer;
 /*margin: 0 auto;*/
 /*margin: 0 40px;*/
 /*float: left;*/
 /*display: inline-block;*/
 border-radius: 5px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.shirt-box:hover {
 transform: translateY(-3px);
}
.container-flex {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow:row wrap;
 align-items: center;
    justify-content:space-around;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="centerpage">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row container-flex">
         <div class="col shirt-box">
            sdfsdfs sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf
         </div>
         <div class="col shirt-box">
            sdfsdfs sdf sdf sdf sdf sdf
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```